# Angular 2 - Waiting for authentication api call to resolve first before making other api requests

Tags: angular, api, authentication

I would like to make call to `api/authenticate` endpoint on my server before making any further requests.

I have many components such as Users, Flights, Airports. They all get data from their corresponding api endpoints. (e.g `api/users`, `api/flights`, `api/airports`)

I am making `api/authenticate` call in ngOnInit() function inside the main component `AppComponent`.

However the problem is that, ngOnInit() function of the nested component `FlightsComponent` sends request to `api/flights` before `api/authenticate` call resolves in ngOnInit() fucntion of `AppComponent`.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to organize the code so that `api/authenticate` request is resolved first before making any further api requests.

Comment: Do you need to call the `api/authenticate` every time? Can you not store a something like token and only call `api/flights` if the token is pressent?

Comment: In addition, you can keep 'authenticated' status somewhere like BehaviorSubject and manipulate you state according to it.

Comment: `api/authenticate` does not need to be called every time. Only once when app is loaded. `api/authenticate` returns a cookie with token. I need that cookie to make the request to `api/flights`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on angular route guards like `CanActivate` and `CanActivateChild` on this angular doc [link](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards), in these guards you can get all the details before routing to the link. Only issue will be everytime it will load the route it will call the service so you have to do some type of cache management(you can use browser storage) so that you can avoid calls to service once you fetch token and all first time.

Comment: Thank you! canActivate route guard is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should run your api/authenticate request only once. (This could be upon user login or whenever you need to start making authenticated api requests)

The api/authenticate should return a token that you should store for subsequent requests. For now, I would suggest using local storage to do this.

I would suggest to :

1. Create a service to handle and store authentication info such as your token.
2. Before making api calls, check if the authorised token is stored locally.
3. Create an http service to make api calls.
4. Use this service in your component and subscribe to wait for a response from your api.

Here is a quick example.

Create an auth service (This is very basic, but will get you started) :

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  setToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
  }

  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");

  }

}
```

Then be sure to add the service to your app.module.ts like so :

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthService } from '../assets/services/auth.service';
import { HttpService } from '../assets/services/http.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpService,AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, when making api calls, I would suggest using an http service that you can create like so :

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

//Perhaps have a flight class to store your model in
import { Flight } from "./classes/flight.ts";

import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  private serverUrl = "http://path/to/your/api"; // base url
  private headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
  });

  private headers_multipart = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': this.authService.getToken()
  });

  constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService) { }

  // All Flight API Calls
  //Example
  getFlights() {
    let url = this.serverUrl + '/Flights';
    return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
  //Or perhaps more specific
   //get a single flight
  getFlight(id: string) {
    let url = this.serverUrl + '/Flights/' + id;
    return this.http.get(url).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

  //or perhaps you need to create a new flight ?
  createFlight(flight:Flight) {
    let url = this.serverUrl + '/Flights';
    return this.http.post(url, flight, {headers: this.headers}).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
```

Then, finally, in your component where you need to wait for the api calls to finish, you should make requests that subscribe to your api calls, so that you can wait and watch the resource until it receives a value.

Here is an example for your component :

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { Flight } from '../../classes/flight';
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

private flights: Flight[] = [];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService,
  private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.httpService.getFlights().subscribe(
      //3 params (data,err,done)
      (data: any) => {
        if(data && data !== "") {
          this.flights = data;

          //more logic here after you have received your flight data
        }
      },(err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    //You can also check if a token is present and use it like so...
    //again, this is very basic and I would encourage to store this in a better way.
    this.token = this.authService.getToken();
    //perform other logic here ...

  }

}
```

Hope this sends you in the right direction !

**EDIT:**

To get the auth token, I am assuming you need to log in to your api with some credentials ?

Then just add another method to your http.service.ts like so :

**http.service.ts**

```
//add this 
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any>{

    let url = this.serverUrl + "/Users/login?include=user";

    return this.http.post(url, {username: username, password: password}, {headers: this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {

      return Observable.throw(err);
    })
  }
```

and then call this login method in your ngOninit on your app component like so :

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { Flight } from '../../classes/flight';
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private flights: Flight[] = [];

    constructor(private httpService: HttpService,
        private authService: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        //first check if the token is set
        if (this.authService.getToken() === "") {
            this.httpService.login(username, password).subscribe(response => {
                //Once you have received the token from the api
                let token = response.id;
                //save the token
                this.authService.setToken(token);

                //now you can do more stuff on ngOnInit here 
                this.httpService.getFlights().subscribe(
                    //3 params (data,err,done)
                    (data: any) => {
                        if (data && data !== "") {
                            this.flights = data;

                            //more logic here after you have received your flight data
                        }
                    }, (err: any) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                );

            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Now anywhere in your app where you need to make authenticated requests to the api, just do a check like if(this.authService.getToken()==="") or you could write this into a seperate method and just call the method etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed answer. I'm not sure when to call setToken() method in auth.service.ts. Ideally I would like to do this in inside ngOnInit() function in AppComponent or somewhere else as long as it is close to app initialization.

Comment: @IvanJ I have added an Edit to my answer. I have not tested it but it should work for you to set the token on app initialisation. While my solution should work for you, I would still suggest to improve on it since it is just an example.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. Thanks for the edit. The only issue for me is that `this.httpService.getFlights()` call is happening in child component of App component. So if I make `api/authenitcate` call from ngOnInit() in AppComponent, I have no way to wait for the response before rendering child module which will make a call to `api/flights` before the response of `api/authenticate`. I have a feeling I might have to use route resolvers.

Comment: @IvanJ how about not adding your child component inside your app.component . Then, once your token has been set, just navigate to your child component using angulars built in router , e.g. this.router.navigate(['/flights']);

Comment: Yes I managed to solve this with canActivate route guards which call authentication service (something like auth.service.ts as you provided in your example). I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a call and be sure that it emits only when its complete, and all the subscribers must be notified after the async call it's made then you can use an AsyncSubject. The async subject is a specialized subject that emits to subscribers only the latest value emitted before the subject's completion. So, if your call to the server is an authorization one, and the whole application needs the value of this call, by using an AsyncSubject, any subscriber, which has subscribed before and after the subject emission, will recieve the value